# Selecting column/field of object collection and exporting as List<>

Tags: c#, linq

I am using a custom object to store patient data

```
class PatientData
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public string BloodType {get; set;}
}
```

I have a `List<PatientData>` and I would like to pull one of the fields from the collection out as a `List<string>`.

Sample data:

```
[{"Brad","Smith","O-pos"},
 {"Stacy","Jenkins","A-neg"},
 {"Fred","Jones","A-pos"},
 {"Kim","Warren","AB-neg"}]
```

I would like to end up with  List such as...

```
["O-pos","A-neg","A-pos","AB-neg"]
```

How do I pull out a single field in the object to accomplish this?

Comment: `patients.Select(p => p.BloodType).ToList()`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev Thanks! .. create an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I think I should not do it. I've posted my comment because I think you have additional constraints (like without duplicates, or get result in specific order). So my comment was just a clarification of requirements. BTW you can write your own answer to your question and accept it

Comment: You should mark an answer....Since the question has been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = (from i in list where i != null select i.BloodType).ToList();
```

This is another way of doing this.

If you don't mind having nulls for those items that are null:

```
var result = (from i in list select i?.BloodType).ToList();
```

list is the instance of `List<PatientData>`

Answer (score 3):

```
var extracted = originalData.Where(item => item != null).Select(item => item.BloodType).ToList();
```

This snippet assumes that original collection may contain `null` elements. Otherwise the `Where` clause can be omitted.